# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. during android build

Tags: ionic3

I'm getting this above error, and it is strange because I never used to get the error before. Also, I'm not using firebase, since similar problems were related to fcm plugin while during the error-research.

This is what I'm getting

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     /Users/tejashripatange/Documents/Project/ProjectName/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/debug/google-services.json
>     /Users/tejashripatange/Documents/Project/ProjectName/platforms/android/app/src/debug/nullnull/google-services.json
>     /Users/tejashripatange/Documents/Project/ProjectName/platforms/android/app/src/nullnull/google-services.json
>     /Users/tejashripatange/Documents/Project/ProjectName/platforms/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
>     /Users/tejashripatange/Documents/Project/ProjectName/platforms/android/app/src/nullnullDebug/google-services.json
>     /Users/tejashripatange/Documents/Project/ProjectName/platforms/android/app/google-services.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, you are using some google service, like example push notification. and if that use service, you have to copy 'google-service.json' file to your project path for use google service. and i think you did platform remove and add again. so deleted that files. and you have to copy that file again or remove your plugins.

Comment: so you have to download 'google-services.json' file. so where is it ? you are using FCM plugin. go to your google firebase console and check your cloud messaging settings, its there. Or, if you don't want this plugin, you can remove it from your project

Comment: Im not using any google service i was just experimenting but had to discard it, removed all the references yet it gives this error. Is there a way to check in the source code?

Comment: please write this code to your terminal and copy to me result
ionic cordova plugin

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzkZ7UgNnvPBBv56KSfOtG4itelTtc_O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: cordova plugin rm cordova-support-google-services --save